# Sample n rows from each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below, I am doing groupby on three fields: 'Subject', 'Rep' and 'yval'.

```
import pandas as pd 
yval = [[1]*30 + [2]*20 + [1]*20 + [2]*30 ]
yval = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, yval)
df = pd.DataFrame({'yval': yval , 'xval':np.random.randn(100)})
df['Subject'] = ['S01'] * 50 + ['S02'] * 50
l = [[x] * 10 for x in range(3)] + [[x] * 10 for x in range(2)] + [[x] * 10 for x in range(2)] + [[x] * 10 for x in range(3)]
l = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
df['Rep'] = l
df


for k, t in df.groupby(['Subject', 'yval', 'Rep']):
    print k 


('S01', 1, 0)
('S01', 1, 1)
('S01', 1, 2)
('S01', 2, 0)
('S01', 2, 1)
('S02', 1, 0)
('S02', 1, 1)
('S02', 2, 0)
('S02', 2, 1)
('S02', 2, 2)
```

I am trying to find a way to select `n` rows from group each. In this example, assuming `n = 2`, we might get the following result. If `n=4`, I expect everything (the entire dataframe).

```
('S01', 1, 0)
('S01', 1, 2)
('S01', 2, 0)
('S01', 2, 1)
('S02', 1, 0)
('S02', 1, 1)
('S02', 2, 1)
('S02', 2, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. What do you mean "pick all data related to two randomly chosen groups"? From the output below I can't seem to infer, do you mean remove two groups?

Comment: In the figure above, I am interested in picking `n` rows from each group, colored by different color.  'Pick all data' means extract the corrsponding data from the actual dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer selects `n` **groups**, whereas OP wants to select `n` rows from each group. Then it should be done as

`ix = np.hstack([np.random.choice(v, n, replace=False) for v in gps.groups.values()])`

where `gps = df.groupby(['Subject', 'yval', 'Rep'])`.

Then `df.iloc(ix)` will give `n` rows selected randomly from each group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here's a way you could do it:

```
import random

# Do the groupby
gps = df.groupby(['Subject', 'yval', 'Rep'])
```

Two options, one is faster but requires more lines.

```
# Option 1: sample (20.6 µs per loop)
group_list = random.sample(gps.groups.keys(), len(gps.groups)-2)

# Option 2: shuffle (15.1 µs per loop)
# Store the dict keys into a list
group_list = list(gps.groups.keys())
random.shuffle(group_list)
# Get all but the last two
group_list = group_list[:-2]
```